# Why is "undefined + x = x" in php?

Tags: php, types, undefined

If we have this code

```
echo $a + 1;
```

php returns: `Notice: Undefined variable: a in...` and also `1`

This is little unclear situation right? if `$a` is undefined (and `$a` is really undefined), why is `undefined + 1` =   `1` ?
result mus be also `undefined` right?
interesting to hear your opinion.

Comment: `undefined` is not like `NaN`. PHP just casts it to 0 in an addition.

Comment: The English adjective "undefined" in a PHP notice doesn't correspond to some special `undefined` value. I'm not sure where you got the impression that that was the case.

Comment: undefined in PHP isn't like an SQL null that infects everything it touches. PHP will warn, but then typecast the unknown value to whatever seems appropriate for the operation being performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for a non-existent variable is `null`. `null` cast to a number is `0`. `0` + a number is this number.

Answer (score 2):

$a + 1 gives php the assumtion $a is of type int. the default value of int cannot be undefined and is 0. then 0 + 1 = 1